# Add div in image

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I add custom php code in gallery.phtml to call attribute about product, but i don't know how to put this code inside image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the code you are using in the edited `gallery.phtml`, but if i understand you correctly, this is just a styles issue. You have a `div` that is used to display a custom block of content and now you want that block to sit on top of the product image. What you need to do is make sure that your custom `div` is nested as a child element of the element you want it to overlap, set the custom `div` to `style="position: absolute;"` and then make sure that the parent element is set to `style="position: relative;"`.

There may be a chance that your element is not in the right place though (placement in M2 is much more complex then it might seem on it's surface), and in that case, you might end up being better off placing your `div` in your `xml` files.

Comment: OK I will do that, but is any option to modify image gallery to automatic add text to image ?